# text file download code in php

Tags: php, file, download

I am a new PHP programmer. I am trying to write code to allow users to download text file from my website. I followed the answers to similar questions on this subject and put together this following test program. It did not force the download to go to a file, instead, it sent the content to the screen (in Chrome, IE, Firefox). Could someone point out what I did wrong?

Here is my test code:

```
<?php
    $file = "test.txt";

    if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

    $type = filetype($file);
    // Send file headers
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"test.txt\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
    header('Expires: 0');
    // Send the file contents.
    set_time_limit(0); 
    readfile($file);
    exit();

?>
```

Comment: the test code did not show up.  I will try again:

Comment: <?php
    $file = "../op/geneComp/upload/test.txt";

    if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

    $type = filetype($file);
    // Send file headers
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"test.txt\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
    header('Expires: 0');
    // Send the file contents.
    set_time_limit(0); 
    readfile($file);
 exit();
 
?>

Comment: There is an "edit" link below your question. You can click it and add the missing code into the question as opposed to adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, "Shadow ");
fclose($handle);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;   filename='.basename('file.txt'));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.txt'));
readfile('file.txt');
exit;
```

Edited , try it on single php page .

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried the suggestion but the content still goes to the screen.  What else can it be wrong?

Comment: Its work properly. Try this on a single php page then u can understand that you have another issue .

Comment: I simply copy your code and ran it on both Chrome 44.0.... and IE11.  Both went to screen.  Yes, I do have another issue, but I am at a loss.  Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

This code will display the text file content in the screen, and user can download it as a text plain file:

```
$file = "test.txt";

if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

$type = filetype($file);
// Send file headers
header("Content-type: $type");
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0');
// Send the file contents.
set_time_limit(0); 
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

But this code (by @Drop Shadow) will force browser to show download dialog without displaying anything:

```
$file = "test.txt";

if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

$type = filetype($file);
// Send file headers
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"test.txt\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0');
// Send the file contents.
set_time_limit(0); 
readfile($file);
exit();
```

Comment: The PHP code by Drop Shadow should work, but I suspect there are other issues with my system that caused the output buffer not sending it to a file but just displayed on the screen.  I have no idea and I am hoping someone may have some suggestions.